# Check null columns MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

I have MDX query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {( [DimDates].[YearMonthNum].[YearMonthNum].ALLMEMBERS )} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsData].[FirstYearMonth].&[2020-01] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Cluster].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Campaign].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsData].[RevenueGenerating].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsData].[Product].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Channel].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM (SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Custom4].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM (SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Custom5].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM (SELECT ( { [TransactionsDataExtra].[Custom6].[All] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM (SELECT ( { [TransactionsData].[ClientId].&[2] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Model])))))))))) 
WHERE ( [TransactionsDataExtra].[Channel].[All],
 [TransactionsData].[Product].[All],
 [TransactionsData].[RevenueGenerating].[All], [TransactionsDataExtra].[Campaign].[All], 
[TransactionsData].[FirstYearMonth] <= ['2020-01'], 
[TransactionsDataExtra].[Cluster].[All], [TransactionsData].[ClientId].&[2] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, 
FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I want to get results where e.g. Custom6 is NULL, or Custom5 is NULL or both of them, or any other filter, or Custom5[NULL, Value]

but I've been struggling to find how to do that and where in the query add changes...   I tried passing nothing like: `[TransactionsDataExtra].[Cluster].&[]` but that didn't return anything at all. Could anyone help me out?

I also looked up ISEMPTY but can't figure out how to add it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fo anyone struggling in the future like noob me use this:
`[DataExtra].[Cluster].&` instead `[DataExtra].[Cluster].&[]`

also, check this amazing Excel extension to view queries: https://olappivottableextensions.github.io/#view-pivottable-mdx